# Adb command sim on off in sim manger(samsung devices)

Tags: android, adb, samsung-mobile

I want to know adb command about sim on/off in sim manger(samsung devices).

Please help me

Thank you

In dual sim mode
//sim manger
Sim1 on
Sim2 on

I send adb command to devices.

result sim2 off

cmd phone disable-physical-subscription 1
=> This cmd is not working